# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code in react native [XCODE 12.5]

Tags: xcode, react-native

I’m currently developing an app in react native and I’ struggling with this error: “Xcode 12.5: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code“.
Now I’ve already tried to:

1. Uninstall and reinstall all thing related to pods.
2. Delete and reinstall node_modules folder.
3. I’ve red there’s something to in keychain but again, it doesn’t work.

I think it could be a permission error or something like that, because it occurs at the end of the app build.

Thank you

Comment: One of your `Build Phases` is failing, have you introduced any recently that may have modified a build phase?

Comment: no, nothing apart installing new dependecies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, run this command in your project folder from temrinal:

```
react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output ./ios/main.jsbundle
```

Comment: Sadly, this solution did not work for me. :-\

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In my case it was unable to resolve module 'react-native-audio' and mistakely copied ../components/react-native-audio from somewhere else..

I hope you had the same error and hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much Rahul, I've already had found a solution, but thanks again.