# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code : React Native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

When I try to build my react native application in Xcode(14.2), I'm getting following error

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I tried `nvm unalias default` but it didn't worked.

Anyone have an idea to fix this build failed issue ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code in react native \[XCODE 12.5\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631053/command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code-in-react-native-xc)

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer to a question for flutter:
[Xcode 14: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73760753/xcode-14-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code)

The issue does not go through the framework, it is configuration in xCode: Modify in Project/Build Phases/Target {yourProject}/Start Packager, check Run Script: For install builds only.

[fix Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4oZb.png)